# Android: secondary display on tablet devices before 4.2

Tags: android, hdmi

I am starting an application which uses a secondary display.
To this display will be drawn a presentation window, controlled from the tablet.

Note : **not** a mirroring of the device screen.

I have seen that creating a secondary display is possible in Android 4.2 and above.
However, I need to cater for devices from Android 4.0 - there are still a large number of devices being sold (even Samsung) which have this version.

I have seen that Mark Murphy had given a presentation about this last year, where he stated that there was limited developer controls available for Android 3.0 to 4.1.

Is there a "workaround" for doing this in Android 4.0 / 4.1 ?

Comment: Specifically, I seem to recall hearing that there's a way to get videos to play on the external display pre-4.2, though I have never researched it. However, if you were looking to do anything other than that, you are out of luck, short of manufacturer-specific SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Mark.  Does this mean that, if I use presentation Activity, my app will still work in 4.0 and above if the user does not use the secondary display aspect ?

Comment: Well, since `Presentation` and kin do not exist before API Level 17, you will need to avoid trying to use such classes on older devices, via Java version guard blocks (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` checks) or similar techniques. My `PresentationHelper` should work on older Android versions, because it bakes in those checks as it deals with `DisplayManager`. So long as you isolate your `Presentation` code to stuff that is triggered by the `showPreso()` callback, you should be safe (and, if not, that's probably a bug in `PresentationHelper`).

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mark.  I now know what to do !